# ActionView module is all automatically imported?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I was finding some difficulties to understand the rails api, watching the ActionView module from the rails api I see it contains the following modules and classes:

```
MODULE ActionView::Context
MODULE ActionView::Helpers
MODULE ActionView::ModelNaming
MODULE ActionView::RecordIdentifier
MODULE ActionView::RoutingUrlFor
CLASS ActionView::Base
CLASS ActionView::DependencyTracker
CLASS ActionView::Digestor
CLASS ActionView::FileSystemResolver
CLASS ActionView::FixtureResolver
CLASS ActionView::LogSubscriber
CLASS ActionView::LookupContext
CLASS ActionView::NullResolver
CLASS ActionView::PartialRenderer
CLASS ActionView::Renderer
CLASS ActionView::Resolver
CLASS ActionView::Template
CLASS ActionView::TestCase
```

But I can't understand which of these modules and classes are automatically aviable from my views??

Answer (score 0):

All of what you listed are available to your views.